# Need a solution to fetch data from array and then push it to state using for each

Tags: reactjs, foreach, fetch, push

Need a solution to fetch data from api and then push it to a state using `forEach` statement only

```
constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            char: [],
            loading: false
        }
    }
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        fetch("/*someURL*/")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
               data.forEach(item =>{
                   this.setState({
                            loading: false,
                            char: this.state.char.push(item)
                })
            })
            })
    }
 render() {
        const text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : this.state.character.data

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{text}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }}
```

the data in my URL is:

`{"page":1,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":1,"email":"@reqres.in","first_name":"abc","last_name":"cba"},{"id":2,"email":"@reqres.in","first_name":"def","last_name":"fed"},{"id":3,"email":"@reqres.in","first_name":"ghi","last_name":"ihg"},{"id":4,"email":"t@reqres.in","first_name":"jkl","last_name":"lkj""},{"id":5,"email":"@reqres.in","first_name":"mno","last_name":"onm"},{"id":6,"email":"@reqres.in","first_name":"pqr","last_name":"rqp"}]}`

And can use `forEach` statement anywhere to get the data correctly

Comment: So you just want to append the new data chars or replace `char` state every after fetch?

Comment: I want to append new data to chars not replacing it after every fetch

Comment: someone already had provided the answer.

Comment: But I need it by using forEach loop

Comment: why do you need forEach? are you modifying each item before appending it to `char` state?

Comment: I need it use it in a table without using map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this instead:

```
...
.then(data => {               
    this.setState({
        loading: false,
        char: [...this.state.char, ...data]
    })
})
...
```

Updating answer to fit all your properties from your response. I assume `this.state.char` should only contain the data from `result.data`

```
//Notice that I changed the parameter name to result
.then(result => {               
    this.setState({
        loading: false,
        char: [...this.state.char, ...result.data],
        page: result.page,
        per_page: result.per_page,
        total: result.total,
        total_pages: result.total_pages
    })
})
```

Alternatively you can just unfold the entire object:

```
.then(result => {               
    this.setState({
        loading: false,
        ...result
    })
})
```

But then your array will not be stored in `this.state.char` but rather `this.state.data`

For more information on the spread operator `...` you can look [here](https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-destructuring-and-es6-spread-operator-e02212af5831).

TLDR; Basically it takes any object or array `{name: "Dennis", age: 29}` unfolds it and merges it with whatever object you're spreading it "into":

`const myObj = { ...{ name: "Dennis", age: 29"}, email: "myemail@example.com" }`

=

`const myObj = { name: "Dennis", age: 29, email: "myemail@example.com" }`

Comment: I'm not getting output from it. its showing this error: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data is not iterable". then I used " char: [...this.state.char, ...data.data]" . Now output is showing only "data" object and not showing remaining objects like page,per_page,etc.,

Comment: @ShashankGunaga I updated my answer. Let me know how it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spread operator` and simply do.

```
.then(data => {
const {char} = this.state;

this.setState({
  loading: false,
  char: [...char, ...data]

})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
fetch("/*someURL*/")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
    this.setState({
       loading: false,
       char: [...this.state.char, ...result.data]
    })
 })
```

Below code used the spread operator to concatenate the existing state data with newly obtained data from API. It is called the spread(...) operator.

```
[...this.state.char, ...result.data]
```

For more details refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: output is showing only "data" object and not showing remaining objects like page,per_page,etc., in the data from api